# How to check the font and font-family Ubuntu is using

Tags: command-line, fonts

I need to check font and font-family that is displaying on the desktop screen. How can I do this from command line.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 already reached EOL.

Comment: Yes I know about it but is there any generalized command or utility that can use.

Comment: *Where* on the screen? Are you looking to parse what's actually used on the screen at a given moment, or just work out what the system-set fonts are?

Comment: I just want to check which are the system-set fonts. But from command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following commands should help you:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name
```

On my system I get:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name
'Sans 11'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 
'Ubuntu 11'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name
'Ubuntu Mono 13'
```

Comment: sorry out of town...

Answer (score 1):

Sylvain Pineau beat me to it...

I suppose you could check `gsettings`.  Do a `list-keys` to get the font based keys on the `org.gnome.desktop.interface` schema, while grepping for font:

```
$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.interface | grep font

monospace-font-name
font-name
document-font-name
```

From there, you can invoke a `gsettings get` for each, as Sylvain explained.  Ex:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name
```